# i am makeing a minecraft ping discord bot and it is throwing this error when my server is offline

Tags: node.js

(node:7548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null
at Client. (C:\Users\RCIIND_4\Desktop\Vs Code\index.js:67:83)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**This is the code**

```
const ms = require('ms')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const config = require('./config.json')

/**
 * This function is used to update statistics channel
 */
const updateChannel = async () => {

    // Fetch statistics from mcapi.us
    const res = await fetch(`https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=${config.ipAddress}${config.port ? `&port=${config.port}` : ''}`)
    if (!res) {
        const statusChannelName = `【】Status: Offline`
        client.channels.cache.get(config.statusChannel).setName(statusChannelName)
        return false
    }
    // Parse the mcapi.us response
    const body = await res.json()

    // Get the current player count, or set it to 0
    const players = body.players.now

    // Get the server status
    const status = (body.online ? "Online" : "Offline")

    // Generate channel names
    const playersChannelName = `【】Players: ${players}`
    const statusChannelName = `【】Status: ${status}`

    // Update channel names
    client.channels.cache.get(config.playersChannel).setName(playersChannelName)
    client.channels.cache.get(config.statusChannel).setName(statusChannelName)

    return true
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Ready. Logged as ${client.user.tag}.`)
    setInterval(() => {
        updateChannel()
    }, ms(config.updateInterval))
})

client.on('message', async (message) => {

    if(message.content === `${config.prefix}force-update`){
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
            return message.channel.send('Only server moderators can run this command!')
        }
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send("Updating the channels, please wait...")
        await updateChannel()
        sentMessage.edit("Channels were updated successfully!")
    }

    if(message.content === `${config.prefix}stats`){
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send("Fetching statistics, please wait...")

        // Fetch statistics from mcapi.us
        const res = await fetch(`https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=${config.ipAddress}${config.port ? `&port=${config.port}` : ''}`)
        if (!res) return message.channel.send(`Looks like your server is not reachable... Please verify it's online and it isn't blocking access!`)
        // Parse the mcapi.us response
        const body = await res.json()

        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(Buffer.from(body.favicon.substr('data:image/png;base64'.length), 'base64'), "icon.png")
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(config.ipAddress)
            .attachFiles(attachment)
            .setThumbnail("attachment://icon.png")
            .addField("Version", body.server.name)
            .addField("Connected", `${body.players.now} players`)
            .addField("Maximum", `${body.players.max} players`)
            .addField("Status", (body.online ? "Online" : "Offline"))
            .setColor("#FF0000")
            .setFooter("Open Source Minecraft Discord Bot")
        
        sentMessage.edit(`:chart_with_upwards_trend: Here are the stats for **${config.ipAddress}**:`, { embed })
    }

})
client.login(config.token)
```

**This is the updated code**

```
const ms = require('ms')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const config = require('./config.json')

/**
 * This function is used to update statistics channel
 */
const updateChannel = async () => {

    // Fetch statistics from mcapi.us
    const res = await fetch(`https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=${config.ipAddress}${config.port ? `&port=${config.port}` : ''}`)
    if (!res) {
        const statusChannelName = `【】Status: Offline`
        client.channels.cache.get(config.statusChannel).setName(statusChannelName)
        return false
    }
    // Parse the mcapi.us response
    const body = await res.json()

    // Get the current player count, or set it to 0
    const players = body.players.now

    // Get the server status
    const status = (body.online ? "Online" : "Offline")

    // Generate channel names
    const playersChannelName = `【】Players: ${players}`
    const statusChannelName = `【】Status: ${status}`

    // Update channel names
    client.channels.cache.get(config.playersChannel).setName(playersChannelName)
    client.channels.cache.get(config.statusChannel).setName(statusChannelName)

    return true
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Ready. Logged as ${client.user.tag}.`)
    setInterval(() => {
        updateChannel()
    }, ms(config.updateInterval))
})

client.on('message', async (message) => {

    if(message.content === `${config.prefix}force-update`){
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
            return message.channel.send('Only server moderators can run this command!')
        }
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send("Updating the channels, please wait...")
        await updateChannel()
        sentMessage.edit("Channels were updated successfully!")
    }

    if(message.content === `${config.prefix}stats`){
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send("Fetching statistics, please wait...")

        // Fetch statistics from mcapi.us
        const res = await fetch(`https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=${config.ipAddress}${config.port ? `&port=${config.port}` : ''}`)
        if (!res) return message.channel.send(`Looks like your server is not reachable... Please verify it's online and it isn't blocking access!`)
        // Parse the mcapi.us response
        const body = await res.json()

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(config.ipAddress);

if (attachment) { new Discord.MessageAttachment(Buffer.from(body.favicon.substr('data:image/png;base64,'.length), 'base64'), "icon.png")
  embed = embed.attachFiles(attachment);
}

embed = embed.setThumbnail("attachment://icon.png")
        .addField("Version", body.server.name)
        .addField("Connected", `${body.players.now} players`)
        .addField("Maximum", `${body.players.max} players`)
        .addField("Status", (body.online ? "Online" : "Offline"))
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setFooter("Open Source Minecraft Discord Bot");
        
        sentMessage.edit(`:chart_with_upwards_trend: Here are the stats for **${config.ipAddress}**:`, { embed })
    }

})
client.login(config.token)
```

Comment: Based on the information present in the question, we can tell you that you should not try to read the property `substr` of a `null` object on line 67 of `index.js`.

Comment: how to fix it ?

Comment: By editing your code so that you don't try to read the property `substr` of a `null` object.  Because `null` has no properties.  It's `null`.

Comment: you use discord ?

Comment: It's *highly likely* that the problem is in your code and not in Discord itself.  You should really start by examining and debugging your code.  Specifically around the line identified in the error message.  Nobody here can fix your code on your computer for you.  But if you can edit the question to provide more specific information about the code which produces the problem, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: updated see now pls

Comment: The reasonable conclusion based on this information would be that `body.favicon` is `null`.  Can you do `console.log(body);` just before that and check the console output to see what it contains?  (Or, failing that, in some way log or output the value of `body` to see what it contains.)  If `favicon` is never there, remove the code which uses it.  If it's sometimes there, perform a `null` check on that value before using it.

Comment: it is giving a json text on doing console.log(body);                                                 {
  status: 'error',
  online: false,
  motd: '',
  favicon: null,
  error: 'failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known',
  players: { max: 0, now: 0, sample: [] },
  server: { name: '', protocol: 0 },
  last_updated: '1627482167',
  last_online: '0',
  duration: 0
}

Comment: now also this error                                                                          
(node:10972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: attachment is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RCIIND_4\Desktop\Vs Code\index.js:70:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: i found this code here https://github.com/Androz2091/minecraft-discord-bot

Comment: In your updated code you've removed `attachment` entirely.  So you would also need to remove anything that *uses* `attachment`.  In general, both in programming and in physical space, something has to *exist* before you can use it.  Since `attachment` now no longer exists, you can't use it.

Comment: i think bro we should communicate in discord or something else

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works.  Information relevant to the question should be included in the question.  If you've made significant changes and are now facing a new, separate issue then you can always ask a new, separate question.

Comment: so what i have done wrong tell me the code so i could fix it in the updated code

Comment: In your updated code you have no variable called `attachment`.  So, using your text editing tools, do a "find" (ctrl-f ?) for the word "attachment" and remove any line or block of code which references it.  Again, if a variable *doesn't exist*, then you can't use it.

Comment: this also i have to remove   the code you gave                                                                                  `let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(config.ipAddress);

if (attachment) { // <--- here
  embed = embed.attachFiles(attachment); `

Comment: Yes.  Since you've changed the nature of the problem, that changes the nature of the solution.

Comment: if i would remove all these thing i want to make work will not work i want that my code will to give message that **Looks like your server is not reachable Please verify it's online and it isn't blocking access** when he is unable to ping the ip

Comment: so now i removed **attachment** from every where `(node:1936) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: sentMessage is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RCIIND_4\Desktop\Vs Code\index.js:72:5)
    at Client.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RCIIND_4\Desktop\Vs Code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] )`

Comment: If you've made further changes to your code, update the question to indicate that.  Also indicate *which line* is producing the error.  It's also likely that this *even further* changes the nature of the original problem and should be a new Stack Overflow question.  To better understand how this community works, you are encouraged to start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.  This is *not* a private tutoring service.

Answer (score 0):

`body.favicon` is `null`, but you're trying to use it here:

```
body.favicon.substr(...)
```

If it's possible for this value to be `null` (and it clearly is) then you can't assume it'll have a value.  You have to check first.  From there, you need to decide what you want your code to *do* when this value is `null`.  For example, you can add a `null` check like this:

```
const attachment = body.favicon ? new Discord.MessageAttachment(Buffer.from(body.favicon.substr('data:image/png;base64'.length), 'base64'), "icon.png") : null;
```

This uses the `?:` conditional operator to check if `body.favicon` has a value.  If it does, proceed as the code currently does.  If it has no value, set `attachment` to `null`.

From there you need to decide what to do when `attachment` is `null`.  You probably can't use it in the Discord API like that.  So you might wrap some logic in conditional checks here too:

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(config.ipAddress);

if (attachment) { // <--- here
  embed = embed.attachFiles(attachment)
        .setThumbnail("attachment://icon.png");
}

embed = embed.addField("Version", body.server.name)
        .addField("Connected", `${body.players.now} players`)
        .addField("Maximum", `${body.players.max} players`)
        .addField("Status", (body.online ? "Online" : "Offline"))
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setFooter("Open Source Minecraft Discord Bot");
```

---

**UPDATE**

In your updated code you have removed the definition of `attachment` entirely.  That would certainly simplify the problem.  If that's what you want to do then you also need to remove any code which *uses* `attachment`.  For example:

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(config.ipAddress);
    .addField("Version", body.server.name)
    .addField("Connected", `${body.players.now} players`)
    .addField("Maximum", `${body.players.max} players`)
    .addField("Status", (body.online ? "Online" : "Offline"))
    .setColor("#FF0000")
    .setFooter("Open Source Minecraft Discord Bot");
```